# Angular 13: Lazy loaded module with multiple outlets not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-routerlink, angular-auxiliary-routes

**Angular version**
^13.3.9

**Problem**
When using multiple outlets and trying to render multiple of then in a lazy module makes the angular router route correctly BUT the outlet is not being rendered.

**Flow (See example)**
User goes to home page url=''. This uses the primary outlet (no name)

User goes to parent page url='Parent:parent' , which creates the Layout for that page and its children. Parents have their own outlet named 'parentRoutes' which gets transformed to 'Parent:' for a cleaner url. Transformation happens in src/app/CustomUrlSerializer

User goes to child page url='Parent:parent/Child:'. Children have their own outlet named 'childRoutes' which gets transformed to 'Child:' for a cleaner url. Transformation happens in src/app/CustomUrlSerializer

**Example**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9qjhw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Routing routes correctly.
Have already tried:

- [Angular2 Routing on lazy-loaded module with multiple named outlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022382/angular2-routing-on-lazy-loaded-module-with-multiple-named-outlets)
- [Angular 10 auxiliary router outlet not working when placed in lazy loaded module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482916/angular-10-auxiliary-router-outlet-not-working-when-placed-in-lazy-loaded-module)

**UPDATE/PROGRESS**

Currently got it to work for the first child clicked. Then it no longer works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use named outlets? When using parent and child components you do not need them, as child components are automatically rendered in the `router-outlet` of the parent component. Named outlets are only used when you are required to have two (or more) outlets on the same component level.

Here is a working stackblitz from your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycn6cn?file=src/app/app.routing.ts